# Unityでterrainを使ったデータのbuildをしているのですが死ぬほど遅いです。どなたか対処法を知りませんか。

Tags: unity3d

現在、Unityでterrainを使って軽く草を生やすなどしてみて、buildしようとしたのですが、とても遅いです。現在表示されている画面は以下になります。どなたか対処法をご存知ないでしょうか？以下が現在pcに表示されているメッセージになります。画像はスマホで撮ったところ、送れる容量をオーバーしてしまったため送れません。

compilng shadar variants (busy for 3:41:45)
Shader Graphs/TerrainGrass - Universal forward: 38400 of 147456 fp